# menu block or view that shows only siblings and parents

Tags: 8, navigation

It seems like this function was removed in drupal 8 so I am trying to find a solution that doesn't involve created a large amount of blocks or hard coding something. (Best would be a block or a view)

I have menu structure like this:

```
Parent 1
- Child 1.1
-- Grandchild 1.1.1
-- Grandchild 1.1.2
- Child 1.2
-- Grandchild 1.2.1
-- Grandchild 1.2.2
Parent 2
- Child 2.2
-- Grandchild 2.2.1
-- Grandchild 2.2.2
```

When I am on Grandchild 1.1.1 I want to see **only** the entire tree of Parent 1 (that means parent 1 plus all of its child and grandchild items), nothing from Parent 2 and below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you need a solution quickly, you may want to see my post in the Menu Block issue queue:

https://www.drupal.org/node/2811337#comment-11752266

It sounds like I had the same issue you had, and this was the only way I could figure to get the behavior. You'll need the patch that introduces "Active Trail" and "Active Trail Parent" first, as options for Menu Block.

Answer (score 2):

It seems this question has an ongoing patch at https://www.drupal.org/node/2811337 (which i found just after offering the bounty! :)

Comment: Yes, this is a major issue with MB right now in my opinion, as the behavior that existed in 7 no longer exists in 8. Patches do exist. I wound up hacking the module for my case to just force it to happen.

Answer (score -3):

You can do this with css if there is no quick fix available by drupal

Comment: Thanks, but as stated in my question, I need the actual data to be printed to the HTML.